# Making Paypal payment using REST API in PHP

Tags: php, curl, paypal

I'm not clear how to put this code example into PHP's CURL structure, specifically, the -d handle.

```
curl -v https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment \
-H 'Content-Type:application/json' \
-H 'Authorization:Bearer EOjEJigcsRhdOgD7_76lPfrr45UfuI43zzNzTktUk1MK' \
-d '{
  "intent":"sale",
  "redirect_urls":{
    "return_url":"http://<return URL here>",
    "cancel_url":"http://<cancel URL here>"
  },
  "payer":{
    "payment_method":"paypal"
  },
  "transactions":[
    {
      "amount":{
        "total":"7.47",
        "currency":"USD"
      },
      "description":"This is the payment transaction description."
    }
  ]
}'
```

I've used the following test call ok, but don't know how to extend that to the example above.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $clientId.":".$secret);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "grant_type=client_credentials");

$result = curl_exec($ch);

if(empty($result))die("Error: No response.");
else
{
    $json = json_decode($result);
    print_r($json->access_token);
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try something like this, -d is the data you want to post.  custom headers are set with CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER.

```
$data = '{
  "intent":"sale",
  "redirect_urls":{
    "return_url":"http://<return URL here>",
    "cancel_url":"http://<cancel URL here>"
  },
  "payer":{
    "payment_method":"paypal"
  },
  "transactions":[
    {
      "amount":{
        "total":"7.47",
        "currency":"USD"
      },
      "description":"This is the payment transaction description."
    }
  ]
}';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  "Content-Type: application/json",
  "Authorization: Bearer EOjEJigcsRhdOgD7_76lPfrr45UfuI43zzNzTktUk1MK", 
  "Content-length: ".strlen($data))
);
```

Have a look at the options here, http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php 
Set curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false); for example if you dont need the headers returned.

Comment: Is this a complete solution? I'm not getting a response. I changed the authorization to the type and access token retrieved from code very similar to that in the first example.

Comment: It's giving Error: No response.

Comment: It's giving only 0 in response...please suggest for correct code

Comment: Result '0' means you're good to go. Check your sandbox, you should see a transaction posted. You can also use curl_exec and get the result.  You can access the following  RESULT,PNREF,RESPMSG,AUTHCODE

Comment: For those who are getting error: No response. If u are using and old php version it wont work because of the OpenSSL handshake problems. I just test with php 5.3.x and it wont work switched to PHP Version 5.6.28 and it works bacause it has a more recent OpenSSL version........Even if u use curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); will still not work

Comment: Works for me. Thanks

Comment: Using this example, I got a weird error (NSS: client certificate not found (nickname not specified), as though the access token was missing. Removing the Content-length header fixed if for me.