# Paypal Rest API Payouts Not Giving Response PHP

Tags: php, rest, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I followed the example on https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/create-single-payout/ however when i try and run my code, I get no error message and not even a response from paypal.

I have tried adjusting pretty much everything but nothing seems to work, I read somewhere about SSL issues so i went about my way trying to research more about that but couldn't find anything. Here is my php code:

```
function payOut(){
   $data = '{
  "sender_batch_header": {
    "email_subject": "You have a payout!",
  },
 "items": [
{
  "recipient_type": "EMAIL",
  "amount": {
    "value": "9.87",
    "currency": "USD"
  },
  "note": "Thanks for your patronage!",
  "sender_item_id": "201403140001",
  "receiver": "yepni@gmail.com"
}
  ]
    }';

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 
"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payouts?sync_mode=true");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION , 6); //NEW ADDITION
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  "Content-Type: application/json",
  "Authorization: Bearer $token", 
  "Content-length: ".strlen($data))
);
}
```

My token is correct, I literally cannot seem to get any type of answer about this.

Comment: you should consider using json_encode() to encode php arrays to JSON. Have you tried testing your curl requests outside of the script?

Comment: what error message do you get? This post is similar to yours, does it help ?https://stackoverflow.com/a/16310841/8260463